# Failure running spring application : NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, classpath

I have some trouble running a java spring application : main component is `fr.sgcib.cva.accounting.Computation` inside `Accounting.jar`.

I am trying this command :

```
java -cp spring/*:./*:spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:log4j-1.2.16.jar:commons-lang3-3.1.jar:commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:spring-asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:spring-expression-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:.:Accounting.jar fr.sgcib.cva.accounting.Computation 3
```

The applicationContext.xml file is located in `spring/`, and looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd      
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">  

<import resource="classpath:spring/persistence.xml"/>

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="fr.aaa.accounting, com.bbb.access"/> 

<util:properties id="jdbcProps" location="jdbc.properties" />   

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
         <value>classpath:configuration.properties</value>
         <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The main class `Computation.java` :

```
package fr.aaa.accounting;

@Component
public class Computation {
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Computation.class);

@Autowired
Runs runs;

public Computation() {
}

public Run initialize(Long runId) {
    Run run = runs.getRun(runId);
    return run;
}

public Runs getRuns() {
    return runs;
}

public void setRuns(Runs runs) {
    this.runs = runs;
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Long runId = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
    logger.info("RUNNING RUN_ID " + runId);

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:applicationContext.xml");
    Computation computer = context.getBean(Computation.class);
    /* etc. */
```

}

The console output I get when running the above command :

```
10:44:41,745 INFO main fr.aaa.accounting.Computation:299 - RUNNING RUN_ID 3
10:44:41,872 INFO main org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext:495 - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@e0b6f5: startup date [Mon Mar 10 10:44:41 CET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
10:44:41,979 INFO main org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory:557 - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@ee22f7: defining beans []; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [fr.aaa.accounting.Computation] is defined: expected single bean but found 0:
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:271)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1101)
    at fr.aaa.accounting.Computation.main(Computation.java:302)
```

Why can't the JVM find that bean ?

Comment: You don't have enough information here.  Beans are reported as 'not found' when a bean they contain is not found (or a bean contained in a bean they contain is not found, etc.).  I don't know if that's the problem.  But you have cut off the stack trace and focused solely on the bean named first; in my experience, the first one named is rarely the problem.  To be fair, the stack trace and/or other dump info usually contains an indication of the problem, but it's usually at the *end* of a chain of messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
 ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:applicationContext.xml);
```

to this:

```
  ("classpath:applicationContext.xml)  // without the star
```

When using the start you are basically creating an empty application context when the file could not be found.